# Generate notification whenever there is any change in database in Real-time Firebase (Kotlin,Android)?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I create a project where I insert and retrieve data from the database in Realtime Firebase. Now I want to generate a notification when a change in database. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

My Project gist is -
https://gist.github.com/anandrex5/dca58b04b72aba0962c20d401381432e

Comment: You could use a cloud Function that sends a notification via [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)

Comment: Sir can you please review my code and tell me the way how I can implement the FCM because I have no idea about it.

Comment: You may search some similar questions on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Firebase+send+notification+via+cloud+function. In addition, I kindly suggest you have a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.